# Base Shoe Gap Coverage

Tags: trim, baseboard

We had our floors refinished but they ripped the original shoe off. I have some gaps that are little more than 1/2 inch from floor to baseboard (which is attached to 100+ year old plaster). Will standard 3/4 inch shoe be high enough for nails to attach?

Comment: With 1/4" to spare it sounds like...

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, but in those spots you may be able to drive the nails diagonally down into the floor. If that doesn't work, try cutting a small wooden filler for the gap, and either glue or nail it into place, then nail the shoe molding to that. The filler doesn't have to fill the entire gap - just the spots where you'll be nailing.

And of course you could just use molding that's higher than 3/4".

Comment: I've tried looking for 1" shoe molding but no one near me nor online seems to have 1/2" x 1" shoe.

Comment: Making your own is an option, depending on what kind of tools you have access to.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue like this and the answer is a pretty definite "no".

If you try with a standard small nail (like a 1" nail) you run the risk of puckering or splintering the shoe because you're nailing on the thin part of the shoe. Instead, what I did was in places where the gap was too large to nail to the baseboard, I used 2.5" nails instead (i.e. a nail gun). This was able to nail squarely in the shoe, but reach the 2x4 base plate instead. It did a reasonably good job of picking it up.